# Problema ao atualizar scope

Tags: ionic

Galera, estou tendo problemas com o $scope. Acontece da seguinte forma; tenho uma var no scope e ao atualiza-la introduzindo mais linhas, a view continua com a mesma altura, assim não permitindo descer o scroll para visualizar todo o conteúdo.

Exemplo do problema:

http://codepen.io/scofield25/pen/NxjmYP

Comment: Em qual cenário ele está inserido? A atualização do valor é feita dentro de um directive, service, controller?

Comment: Segue um exemplo do erro: http://codepen.io/scofield25/pen/NxjmYP

Comment: Mas qual o real problema? Ali ele adicionou mais conteúdo e eu pude descer até o fim da page, sem problemas. Porém não é com scroll e sim clicando e arrastando, pois acredito ser voltado a mobile, correto?

Comment: Sim, é que estou utilizando o Framework Ionic, que complica AngularJS para mobile, dê uma olhada novamente no código, atualizei.

Answer (score 0):

Altere seu ***ion-content***. Eu fiz um teste aqui no codepen, veja se no mobile funciona.

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
```

Comment: Isso só irá funcionar para Navegadores Web Desktop, o mobile tem um modo diferente de scroll que ignora essa opção.

Comment: e se você usar o $ionicScrollDelegate.resize(); ? Codepen deu certo:

$scope.zuar = function(){
    $scope.teste = $scope.teste+$scope.teste;
      $ionicScrollDelegate.resize();
  };

Comment: Já tentei também, mas no mobile não faz muita diferença.